# How to grab the note attribute from Message in mido?

Tags: python, midi, mido

I'm trying to print out the note attribute in each message output by mido in a .mid file. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
for msg in mid.tracks[1]:
    if not msg.is_meta:
        print(msg.note)
```

But, upon running the code, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'note'
```

I'm confused, as [the documentation](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#messages) shows the same "msg.note" syntax working just fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `print(mid.tracks[1])` and see what object it is, because it doesn't seem like a msg object.

Comment: It simply prints '<midi track u'Piano' 1695 messages>' 1695 times. The messages print normally with 'print(msg)', just not when I try to grab the note. Using type(), mid.tracks[1] is of type '<class 'mido.midifiles.tracks.MidiTrack'>'.

Comment: Which version of the library are you using?? Do you have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of MIDI messages, and not all of them have a note number.

If you want to print out all notes, you have to check the message type first.
If you want to print out all messages, you cannot rely on the `note` field being there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if not msg.is_meta:
   if msg.type == 'note_on':
      print(msg.note)
```

This should produce just the numerical notes as output.